# Wanna built a new 2d array with n-numbers right and left form the maximum value x in a numpy array BUT the left site might be n<x?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this:

```
pI= np.array([[0,0]])
pI=np.append(pI,[[float(q),float(I)]],axis=0)
```

and read in several .csv

```
Eingabe_Höhe = int(input("Höhe?"))

Eingabe_Breite = int(input("Breite?"))

for i in range(Eingabe_Breite):
   for k in range(Eingabe_Höhe):
       phI = read_pI(arguments[k+i*Eingabe_Höhe])
       print(arguments[k+i*Eingabe_Höhe], i ,k)
       print(phI)
       I_max = np.max(phI[:,1])       
       print(I_max)
       I_max_index = np.argmax(phI[:,1])
       print(I_max_index)
       phI_max = phI[(I_max_index-50 ):(I_max_index+50)]
       print(phI_max)
```

And here is my prob:

```
 phI_max = phI[(I_max_index-50 ):(I_max_index+50)]
```

In some cases, `I_max_index -50` is out of range. Only "10" e.g is possible, but I never know in advance, how much "left" i can go.

How can I tell the program only to go to Index "0" and not try to go "more left"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like:

```
phI_max = phI[max(I_max_index - 50, 0):I_max_index + 50]
```

Comment: This gives this error: phI_max = phI[(I_max_index - 50, 0):(I_max_index + 50)]
Error: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ meth

Comment: This is strange, as from the code you shared I would expect the indices to be of type int (that is what the error is about). Are you sure the code you shared is the same you are actually using? Also, if you can try to give a broader overview of what you are trying to do, we can try to give better insight. The code has for sure other strange parts (for instance, why using both `np.max` and `np.argmax` on the same array?).

Comment: Does this makes sense?:  if I_max_index>=50
           phI_max = phI[(I_max_index-50):(I_max_index+50)] 
       if I_max_index<50:
           phI_max=phI[:(I_max_index+20)]

Comment: I tought, that np.max gives me only the value and np.argmax the index.

Comment: Yes, but you can get the value from the index. Concerning the code you wrote, it may work, but is overcomplicated for such a simple task. As I said, you are probably inadvertently triggering a conversion to float somewhere for the indices. I do not see this in the code you posted, but you may want to double check.

Comment: now i got your point! Thanks. Yes, if i have the index,I of course also have the value. Ah! klaro!